# TypeError with Firebase Functions: Cannot Read Properties of Undefined (Reading 'arrayUnion')

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm new to Firebase Functions and I'm encountering a TypeError when trying to use `FieldValue.arrayUnion`. The error message is `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'arrayUnion')`. I'm trying to update a document in Firestore by adding multiple items to an array field in the document.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```js
// Firebase SDKs
import { logger } from "firebase-functions/v2";
import { onRequest } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import admin = require("firebase-admin");
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

initializeApp();

interface Item {
  itemCategory: number;
  itemIndex: number;
  itemTimestamp: number;
  itemCount: number;
  itemStatus: number;
}

exports.handleItemRequest = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  debugger;
  try {
    const { sectorID, locationID, itemRequests, entityID } = req.body.data;

    // Process each user's item requests
    for (const userID of Object.keys(itemRequests)) {
      itemRequests[userID] = itemRequests[userID].filter((item: Item) => {
        // Remove item request if count is 0 or less
        if (item.itemCount <= 0) {
          return false;
        }

        // Set status to 0 if not already 0
        if (item.itemStatus !== 0) {
          item.itemStatus = 0;
        }

        return true;
      });
    }

    // Firestore document reference
    const docPath = `entities/${entityID}/sectors/${sectorID}` +
                `/locations/${locationID}`;
    const docRef = getFirestore().doc(docPath);

    // Update the confirmedItems field
    // Broken into multiple lines to adhere to max-len rule
    await docRef.update({
      confirmedItems: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
        ...Object.values(itemRequests).flat(),
      ), // Added trailing comma
    });

    // Success response
    res.json({success: true});
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      logger.error("Error handling item request: ", error);
      res.json({success: false, error: error.message});
    } else {
      logger.error("Unexpected error type");
      res.json({success: false});
    }
  }
});
```

In this code, I am attempting to update the `confirmedItems` field in a Firestore document with an array of items. However, when I run this function, I encounter the mentioned TypeError. I've initialized the Firestore and the admin SDK at the beginning of my file, as shown in the code.

I would appreciate any guidance on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Thank you in advance for your help!

PD: I’m using typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion` isn't the correct way to use FieldValue with the Firebase Admin SDK.  The correct way is like this:

```
import { FieldValue } from "firebase-admin/firestore"

docRef.update({
    fieldName: FieldValue.arrayUnion(...)
});
```